Play video with VLC on Windows from Windows PC using ssh
I want to play video on the Windows PC #2 with VLC by ssh.
I am using Windows PC #1 and I can ssh to another Windows PC #2.
I type the following command on ssh, but it seems to run VLC in the background.
vlc.exe "file:///C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.mp4"

Is any way to run VLC in the desktop?
Thanks!

Do you want to run VLC on remote PC#2 or you want to see remote video file on PC#1 ? Anyway I suggest this is your answer

Thank you. Finally, I use schtasks to schedule vlc task instantly.
